# Setting user based UI (background, theme, etc) in Web Application - T3, Next

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am trying to build simple full stack application by using T3 (Next - /pages, tRPC, Prisma, Next-Auth).

Because my application is based on user specific data, I am trying to add user preference page for setting user based UI.

I tried to store the preference data to the backend and fetch it to the client with the SSR rendering method to adjust the UI before they got mounted to prevent flickering Issues and such.

But the problem is, I can't access the client side object (window, document etc) when they are rendered on the server which means I can't set CSS classnames to any elements.

After this, I tried different approach with the cookie / local storage but the results are almost same because local storage is also client object and for cookie I can't set CSS classnames.

If I choose to compromise and use useEffect to wait until the client get hydrated with the JS, I get another issue for flickering UI.

I researched about the problem and found some solutions about the injecting script tag before the client script mounted inside _document.tsx but I am not sure if I can utilize this for setting backgrounds inside Layout components (I am thinking for setting animated lottie-backgrounds).

I am completely lost right now and cannot come up with any kind of ideas.

What approach can I take in this situation?

How can I attach client / backend to generate selectable UI?

Should I just give up this features or take different approach the implement?

Thank you for reading!

Researched hours and hours

Read related docs and blogs

Comment: which version of next are you using and are you using? And if 13, app or pages router?

Comment: now Im using next 13.2.4 and pages routing

Comment: OK, you can in fact "set CSS classnames" server side with Next.js. Using `getServerSideProps` you can fetch the user preference and then using a homogenous layout component for all your pages you can pass the server side props to it and therein set class names and styles without any flicker. Is there a specific reason preventing you from doing this?

Comment: Firstly, im not sure if Im really following what you are saying sorry. Now Im using layout component in my /components dir, but it is only used for setting header on top of the pages and all the detailed css applied into specific component / page.tsx. About getServerSideProps, getServerSideProps itself is not a problem. They are fetching what I intended to fetch. The real problem is I cannot get access client side object (document, window) so I don't know how to interact with css and html with javascript. So can you explain in detail please?

Comment: you don't need access to any client-side variables. Simply set a class name of a parent div in your layout component to for example "dark". Then in your css write `.dark .button { background: black }`. Now only if the user has set dark as their preference will the button be dark. This is what SSR is.

Comment: I realized it as soon as I uploaded the comment above....^^; Thanks to your answers it made my head little more clear! But I encountered another issue which is where should I fetch the data. Im using tRPC right now and I don't know why but I cannot use getInitialProps, getServerSideProps inside _document, _app file. I think tRPC somehow prevents it but Im not sure. Layout.tsx is inside component so I am little confused where should I contorl whole layout with the props. Do you have any ideas? Thanks for your efforts!

Comment: that's why you use a layout component and not _document or _app. `getServerSideProps` only works in page files. Pass the props from the page to the layout. The Next docs are great, I recommend perusing them before making anything with Next.

Comment: Thanks!! I have to read through it carefully. You helped a lot!